# Window/Dialog name is not being captured while recording script for Desktop Application in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

How can I capture the Window/ Dialog of a Desktop Application using UFT when the Window/Dialog Name is not getting reflected while recording the Desktop Application using UFT. Have tried using Object SPY to capture the Window/Dialog Name, and the Window is getting detected also but it is not able to identify elements in that particular window when the Script is Run in UFT

Comment: Please add a minimal code example to clarify your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Have you loaded the correct Add-in so that UFT can identify your application correctly? For example, if you have a Java desktop app, you have to load Java addin.

Comment: Record and Run Settings --> Standard Windows --> Run on any Open Window. Is it selected?